# CheckBox unchecked in List<> not working

Tags: android, list

Would you be able to help me if the checkbox is  !isChecked, why not delete the item from the list?

This code:

```
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                String str = fajlLista.get(position).getName();
                if (isChecked){
                    kijeloltFajlok.add(new Fajlok(str));

                    String x = "";
                    for (Fajlok a : kijeloltFajlok){
                        x += a.getName() + "\n";
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(context, x, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    kijeloltFajlok.remove(str);
                    String x = "";
                    for (Fajlok a : kijeloltFajlok){
                        x += a.getName() + "\n";
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(context, x, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that `kijeloltFajlok` is an object of type List, ArrayList or similar (some object´s container), if you want remove an item of list using `remove` method you should send as parameter the object you want to remove. Looking at your code, you are sending as parameter a `String` object, the one you get with this line:

```
String str = fajlLista.get(position).getName();
```

But this String never will be in the array, then no objects will be removed. Iy you want remove an object, you should send as parameter the `Fajlok` object you want to remove.

Comment: Thank you for your help, if you do not invite me, I will not notice it.

Answer (score 0):

So I guess your list 'kijelolFajlok' is of type Fajlok, since you are adding newFajlok in your if statement.
When you try to remove something from the list, you are removing 'str' which is a string, and not a Fajlok object. Either use the Fajlok objects, or Strings, but not both like you did.